# Los links href dentro de la misma carpeta no funcionan

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

cada vez que realizo mi proyecto web y consigo la ayuda de ustedes (que la agradezco enormemente) me encuentro con cada vez mas problemas de lo mas extraños posibles.

Resulta que tengo una tabla que me trae los datos que están dentro de una base de datos, básicamente es un CRUD de empleados, el cual cuando le doi al boton de visualizar o editar debería de redireccionarme a ese empleado en especifico a traves del id, en la pagina principal, donde tengo otra tabla funciona de maravilla, y esta que tiene exactamente los mismos parametros pero que se encuentra en otra carpeta sencillamente no funciona, a continuación el código por el cual redirecciono a el id de ese empleado:

```
<a href="visualizar.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title"Ver" class="btn btn-sm btn-sm-info"> <i class="bi bi-search"></i> </a>
```

el $row sale de la siguiente sentencia que se encuentra dentro de un while que me permite traer los datos a la tabla junto con los botones que necesito que redireccionen.:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)
```

Entonces explicando mas a fondo, tengo una base de datos de empleados, la cual registro empleados que se muestran en una tabla y por medio de esta la conecto a otra tabla que es parecida pero con otra información, esta tabla me trae los datos de los empleados con otros datos que necesito que se muestren.

La tabla principal, osea la base de datos se encuentran en la carpeta principal del proyecto y la segunda se encuentra en otra carpeta segundaria, pero es en esta donde no funcionan los links.

No se que estoy pasando por alto, no se si tengo que tener alguna sentencia en especial por estar en otra carpeta, pero me ha tocado tener el proyecto freando por que necesito consultar una información para poder editar y no lo logro.

EDIT: Anexo imágenes de donde se encuentra la carpeta Principal y la segundaria.

[image: Carpeta Principal llamada BDV5]

Y la carpeta segundaria que se aprecia en la imagen se llama Ausentismo, que es donde los links hacia las mismas páginas de esa carpeta simplemente no redireccionan.

En cuanto a la consola no arroja ningún tipo de error, no me muestra nada, cuando pongo el cursor encima del botón me muestra la dirección a la cual en teoría debería de redireccionar pero sencillamente no lo hace.

[image: Estos son los archivos que están contenidos dentro de la carpeta ausentismo]

Estos son los archivos que están contenidos dentro de la carpeta ausentismo, dentro del index.php por medio de una tabla al darle clic al botón de visualizar esa fila con la id incluida debería de ir al archivo que se llama visualizar.php con el siguiente link y sentencia de código:

```
<a href="visualizar.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title"Ver" class="btn btn-sm btn-sm-info"> <i class="bi bi-search"></i> </a>
```

Ahora, cuando doi clic al botón que me debería de llevar al archivo que necesito me manda al index.php.

Cualquier parte del código que necesiten, cualquier ayuda o alternativa es bienvenida y muchísimas gracias a todos por ayudarme en mis anteriores preguntas.

Saludos.

Comment: Pero el problema en sí cuál es, ¿no se construyen bien los enlaces, dan error 404? Pon un ejemplo de cómo están quedando tus enlaces y muestra tu estructura de archivos, de modo que se vea, dónde está el código y dónde está el archivo al que quieres ir desde el link.

Comment: Si dices que en la pagina principal funciona, pero en una carpeta no, lo mas probable es un error 404 como dice @A.Cedano . Comparte capturas de tu consola, a lo mejor te da ideas del error, si es que no te dice tal cual es.

Comment: Simplementen no cargan, solo me redireccionan a la página principal, no al ID que necesito, Mi carpeta principal es una llamada BD y dentro de BD se encuentra una que se llama Ausentismo que es la que no me redirecciona a los archivos que necesito.

Comment: Estoy confundido, tiene una página en la carpeta principal con enlaces a páginas en la carpeta secundaria?  Y el href refiere a "./Ausentismo/visualiar.php" pero no funciona?  Y que propósito tiene la ubicación del BD?  Y cuál OS?  Si es Linux, mayusuclos importan.

Comment: No, a lo que me refiero es que, en mi carpeta principal todos los links hacia otros archivos funcionan correctamente, pero, en la carpeta Ausentismo que es casi igual a la principal los links para acceder a esos otros archivos no funcionan, simplemente no redireccionan. la carpeta se llama BDV5 que solo es un nombre alusivo a la información que contiene allí nada más y el sistema operativo es Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se que el tema es un poco enredado, quizás faltó un poco de explicación pero he logrado darle solución, por alguna razón que desconozco el xampp con el que hosteo en un servidor local el proyecto no permitió que se pudiera usar esta sentencia.

La solución que encontré y dije pues que quizás funcionaría era subir el proyecto a un hosting que poseo y de sorpresa funcionaron, no sé si hay que configurar algún parámetro dentro del xampp pero subiendo mis archivos al hosting funcionó sin problemas y ya me redirige donde necesito.

Si conocen cual es la razón de esto por favor publicarla y así podremos ayudar si a alguien más le pasa esto.

Saludos.